# Perl: Getting the innerHTML from the object model, not the "source"

Tags: perl, innerhtml

I am processing a webpage with Perl using [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aAll) and the `io($url)` function.

The pages I am processing ostensibly have well formed URLs. e.g.

```
http://www.forbes.com/billionaires/list/#page:15_sort:0_direction:asc_search:_filter:All%20industries_filter:All%20countries_filter:All%20states
```

Note the `#page:15_`

When I view the source or print out the source return fromm `io()` I see names that appear on page 1 of the website, e.g.,

```
<!-- Start: list_row -->
<tr>
  <td class="rank">1</td>
  <td class="company">
    <a href="/profile/carlos-slim-helu/">
      <img src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/carlos-slim-helu_50x50.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Carlos Slim Helu & family</h3>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="worth">$73 B</td>
  <td>73</td>
  <td>telecom</td>
  <td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
```

However, if I open the page up in developer tools in the browser and look through the object model I see the entries in the list for the people I expect to see on page 15 e.g.,

```
<TR>
  <TD class=rank>1342</TD>
  <TD class=company><A href="/profile/park-hyeon-joo/">
    <IMG alt="" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/park-hyeon-joo_50x50.jpg"> 
    <H3>Park Hyeon-Joo</H3></A>
  </TD>
  <TD class=worth>$1 B</TD>
  <TD>54</TD>
  <TD>Mirae</TD>
  <TD>South Korea</TD>
</TR>
```

Can I get Perl to open the page *and* give me the right contents?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like that page is updating the table using AJAX.  Your `io($url)` is just issuing a simple GET.  Look at https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support for places to start investigating.

Comment: Thanks Rick will have a look--in your opinion is Mech the way to go?

Comment: OK @RickF have tried pQuery::DOM and Web::Query ->text methods and they still return the values from page 1 not page 15. Is there a way to do this in pQuery, Web or is mechanize the way to go?

Comment: OK, I am working with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox.  Will apprise.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little poking around.  The data for the table is actually loaded from this url: `http://www.forbes.com/ajax/load_list/?type=person&uri=billionaires&year=2013`

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, it might be easier to fetch that and parse it (it's JSON formatted).

Comment: how did you find this data table URL??

Comment: I looked tthrough the persist folder and found a listcombined.js that referenced the ajax/load_list url part and variables for type, uri and year. Didn't see how the actual variabels were set... Give me a hint and I will see if I can find the ajax equiv for the profile pages as well. Thx. BTW, Mechanize still a great recommendation as an alt to the ajax url.

Comment: I found it by using the Chrome developer tools, particlarly the Network tab.  Most modern browsers have some equivalent.

Comment: Rick,  I looked in Chrome Network tab (and elsewhere)--couldn't find a reference to ajax/load_list...

Comment: It can be tricky to spot at first - it only shows the last part of the URL in the Name panel, in this case it's just `?type=person...`.  It's categorized as XHR (buttons along the bottom can filter by category).  Also make sure you have the Network panel open before you open the page, or reload the page after opening the panel.

Comment: Found, it I had to click the next arrow.  Just pasting in the the "paged" url didn't do it.